# c# left-shift nibbles in a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-manipulation

Here is the requirements of my function:

take the following string:

```
6900460420006149231=13050010300100000
```

and convert it to the following byte array:

```
{ 0x37, 0x06, 0x90, 0x04, 0x60, 0x42, 0x00, 0x06, 0x14, 0x92, 0x31, 0xD1, 0x30, 0x50, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00 }
```

The first byte 0x37 is the original length of the string in binary.  The next 10 bytes is the string "6900460420006149231" encoded in bcd format.  This is where this gets tricky.  Now I need the Hex 'D' to represent the separator(=) between the two fields.  You can see the hex in the high nibble of the 12 index in the byte array.  The rest of the byte array is the second field "13050010300100000" encoded in bcd format.  If the original length is an odd number, I put a leading zero to pad the first half-byte of unused data.

I don't expect a full implementation from anyone so lets break this down and address where I am having trouble.
Lets say I have:

```
byte[] field1Bytes = { 0x06, 0x90, 0x04, 0x60, 0x42, 0x00, 0x06, 0x14, 0x92, 0x31 }
byte[] field2Bytes = { 0x01, 0x30, 0x50, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00 }
byte separator = 13; // D  0x0D
```

If I simply use Array.Copy, I would end up with:

```
{ 0x06, 0x90, 0x04, 0x60, 0x42, 0x00, 0x06, 0x14, 0x92, 0x31, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x30, 0x50, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00 }
```

The above byte array isn't quite what I need.. Any idea on how I could implement the following function to get me closer to what I am trying to achieve:

```
byte[] ShiftLeftAndCombine(byte[] b1, byte[] b2)
```

where

```
ShiftLeftAndCombine({0x0d}, {0x01, 0x30})
```

would return

```
{0xd1, 0x30}
```

- on a side note I realize I need to handle even/odd field lengths to address the actual function I am writing, but let me worry about that =]

Comment: Nope, its work work.  I get paid...

Comment: Haha ok, wasn't sure as it sounded like a homework question! :)  My answer below assumes homework, I'll update it if you need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is homework or not, but the shift left and combine part will look something like this:

```
var pos = 0;
var newByte = b1[pos] << 4;
newByte |= b2[pos]
```

Obviously you'll want to do that in a loop and take into account the length of the 2 arrays

Comment: Wouldn't the left-shift operator need to be 4, rather than one?

Comment: Yes 4.  I will give this the correct answer but I am now going with a different implementation that I will share when I am done.  Basically I will treat each char in the string as a byte { 0x06, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x06, 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0x04, 0x09, 0x02, 0x03, 0x01, 0x0D, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 } and then combine

Comment: @aelstonjones ok great, would like to see how you implemented it

Answer (score 1):

What you're really needing to do is shift the entire second block of memory left four bits, seems to me. That means you'll do more than copy, you'll be shifting the "leading" (most significant) bits of byte n+1 into the "trailing" (least significant) nth byte. Here's a generic "bit shifter" for an array of bytes.

```
    byte[] shiftBlock(byte[] bytes, short bitShift)
    {
        byte[] newBytes = new byte[bytes.Length+1];
        for (int index=0;index < bytes.Length; index++)
        {
            // Each new byte is the current byte shifted left by "bitShift" bits,
            // followed by the first 8-bitShift bits of the next byte OR zero,
            // if we're at the end of the array. Shift the next-bytes bits to
            // the right, and OR the result together. 

            byte newByteMSB = (byte)(bytes[index] << bitShift); // shift left bitShift bits
            byte newByteLSB = (byte)((index==bytes.Length-1)?((byte)0):(bytes[index+1]));
            newByteLSB = (byte) (newByteLSB >> (8-bitShift));

            newBytes[index] = (byte) ( newByteMSB | newByteLSB);

        }

        return newBytes;
    }
```

You should be able to adapt this into a broader solution with the necessary caveats. I gave it a cursory test and it appears to work on the simple byte arrays I threw at it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks David,  I just solved my function but I will bookmark this for next time =]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** modified to not include the original length in the result.

Hope this helps.  Not sure how you calculated the original length to have a value of 0x37, though. :)

Based on the stated desired result, you only need to shift the separator nybble into the first byte of the second array.

```
byte[] field1Bytes = { 0x06, 0x90, 0x04, 0x60, 0x42, 0x00, 0x06, 0x14, 0x92, 0x31 } ;
byte[] field2Bytes = { 0x01, 0x30, 0x50, 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00 } ;
byte separator = 13; // D  0x0D 

byte[] result = new byte[field1Bytes.Length + field2Bytes.Length];


Array.Copy(field1Bytes, 0, result, 0, field1Bytes.Length);
Array.Copy(field2Bytes, 0, result, field1Bytes.Length, field2Bytes.Length);

// shift the separator into the first byte of the second array in the result
result[field1Bytes.Length] |= (byte)(separator << 4);
```

This produces:

```
0x06 0x90 0x04 0x60 0x42 0x00 0x06 0x14 0x92 0x31 0xd1 0x30 0x50 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00
```

... which matches the stated desired result.

Comment: This doesn't shift the field2Byte array left as I think the OP intended - just the operator...assuming I'm interpreting the OP's question correctly :)

Comment: @DavidW The output seems to match his desired output.  Based on his desired result, only the first byte of the second array needs to have the separator value shifted in.  The values of the second array do not need to be shifted at all.

Comment: Hmmm...understand what you're saying, Monroe, but for the moment I'm going to respectfully disagree. If the point is to "pack" the two byte arrays with the 0xd "sandwiched" in the middle, it sure seems to me you'll have to consider shifting the contents of the 2nd array four bits left or you'll introduce four errant zero bits when you decode the information. Maybe wrong, who knows :)

Comment: @DavidW Just going off of his stated result.  If the first byte of the second array >= 0x80, then there could be some wierd results, to be sure.  But in that case it seems you would want to shift the second array four bits *right* in order to protect the upper nybble of the first byte from being lost.  I think the OP was using the term 'left shift' to describe how the separator is treated, and  then things got conflated from there.  But without more feedback from the OP, this point is ambiguous.

Comment: Agree, Monroe, but it looks his problem has been solved. But that bitshifting code might come in handy some day :)  Blessings...

Answer (score 0):

I would make a BCD class.  Then BCD.ToByteArray() would give you the current representation of the BCD in Byte[] format, and BCD.ToString() would give the string format.  Internally store the BCD as one array element per BCD digit.  If you design your own datastructure rather than try to make Byte[] do what it wasn't intended to do, you will be better off.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string rawTrack = "6900460420006149231=13050010300100000";

        var byteList = new LinkedList<byte>();

        foreach (var c in rawTrack)
        {
            if(c.Equals('='))
            {
                byteList.AddLast(13);
                continue;
            }

            var bytes = Formatters.Bcd.GetBytes(new string(c, 1));  // for 9 gives 0x09
            byteList.AddLast(bytes[0]);
        }

        // Adjust Buffer if odd length
        if(rawTrack.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            byteList.AddFirst(0);
        }

        var result = new byte[byteList.Count / 2];
        var buffer = new byte[byteList.Count];
        byteList.CopyTo(buffer, 0);

        var j = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < buffer.Length - 1; i += 2, j++ )
        {
            result[j] = CombineLowNibble(buffer[i], buffer[i + 1]);
        }


        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(result));
    }

    private static byte CombineLowNibble(byte b, byte b1)
    {
        return (byte) ((b << 4) | b1);
    }
```

Here is the result:

```
06-90-04-60-42-00-06-14-92-31-D1-30-50-01-03-00-10-00-00
```

Comment: Nice work!  If you can get your values in to the byte arrays `field1Bytes` and `field2Bytes`, then you'll find my answer will perform faster.  But if you are happy with the performance of your solution, go for it!  If you are dealing with small lengths then you'll find that `List<byte>` will be much faster than `LinkedList<byte>`.

Comment: I needed the linked list for add first.  Thank you for your answer

Comment: `List<byte>.Insert(0, value)` will also let you insert something at the beginning.  And for small lists, this will still be faster overall than using LinkedList<byte>.  Or, check for odd *before* the `foreach` loop, and then just add the first zero byte.  Then you never have to insert at the beginning.